# Best way to struct data to Plot a chart in Django

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

In order to plot a chart with Highcharts I have to structure a queryset in a list of dictionaries that have to look like the following:

```
[{
name: 'Europe',
data: [{
  name: 'Germany',
  value: 767.1
},  {
  name: "Cyprus",
  value: 7.2
}]
}, {
name: 'Africa',

data: [{
  name: "Senegal",
  value: 8.2
}, {
  name: "Ghana",
  value: 14.1
 }]
}]
```

The following code  is the way I tried. The data is structured as requested and the graph is plotted good, but the final list (listsocios)  is missing some values and repeating another ones. I guess it is memory issue. Whats your thoughs? Whats would be the more effecient way to struct?

```
class GraphSociosProvinciasView(TemplateView):
 template_name = 'socios/socios_prov_graph.html'
 def get_context_data(self,*args, **kwargs):
    context = super(GraphSociosProvinciasView, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
    listsocios=[]
    listsocprov=[]
    #Por cada provincia guardo los socios
    for n in range(1,25):
        sociosp=Socios.objects.all().filter(provincia=n)
        TotalSocios=sociosp.count()
        listsocprov.clear()
        if TotalSocios!=0:
            for socp in sociosp:
                listsocprov.append({'name': socp.apellido,'value': socp.numero_socio},)
                nombre_provincia=socp.get_provincia_display()
            listsocios.append({'name':nombre_provincia,'data':listsocprov})
    print(listsocios)
    context={
    'sociosprov': listsocios,          
    }
    return context
```

Comment: Hi @wwrandazzo, You have used `highcharts` tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Comment: Hi ppotaczek u r right. I pulled off highcharts from the post's tags.